# about $_POST warning

Tags: post, undefined, notice

I have a problem with `$_POST`. I am adding data to my mysql database with this code and it is working.;

```
if (isset($_POST["d_kayit"])){
     $denetci=$dbpdo->prepare("INSERT INTO denetciler(name,pass) VALUES(:name, :pass)");
     $denetci->bindParam(":name",$_POST["denad"],PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $denetci->bindParam(":pass",$_POST["sif"],PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $denetci->execute();
}
```

But in the same form i want to use `$_POST["denad"]` for another insert. It is giving me `"Notice: Undefined index: denad in"` error. Sample code that giving error is;

```
if (isset($_POST["add"]))
{
    echo "Person: ".$_POST["denad"];
}
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: it is not duplicated question. I have looked before ask. If I dismiss something please show me.

Comment: You are checking whether `add` is in the post array and read data from `denad`. So why do you check for one key and then read another?

Comment: i have a button. i am checking if button is pushed. if button pushed i am tring to read the text.

Answer (score 0):

If this:

```
if (isset($_POST["add"]))
{
    echo "Person: ".$_POST["denad"];
}
```

is yielding notice: `Undefined index: denad` then you probably don't have inputs "add" and "denad" on the same form. Or it is an unchecked checkbox.

Edit based on the code of your HTML form. You'll need something like this, you can't end your form with `</form>` like you did until you included all needed input fields:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <!-- content here -->
    <input name="denad" id="denad" type="text" style="margin-top:2px; width:200px; height:30px;"></input>
    <input type="submit" class="get_file" id="K_ekle" name="add" onclick="test()" value="Kişiye Ekle" style="float:left;"></input>                    
    <!-- more content here -->
 </form>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer Herco but there isn't any problem with $_POST["add"] because i tried echo "message" code and it worked. both of add and denad in same form.

Comment: i have <div> parts. when i use $_POST["denad"] in the <div> part where i defined, my codes working. but the other <div> part of same form is giving error.

Comment: Yes I understand there's no problem with "add", otherwise you can't get to the notice I quoted. On your form, do you also have something like `<input name="denad" />`?

Comment: Yes; <input name="denad" id="denad" type="text" style="margin-top:2px; width:200px; height:30px;"></input>

Comment: Please show the HTML contents of `<form>` to `</form>` in your question

Comment: i tried to get value of denad with javascript. when i use var denad = document.getElementById("denad").value i am getting value with an alert("denad").

Comment: Your form is not posting both `add` and `denad` at the same time. I can not help you without seeing how you post your form.

Comment: my form is very long. can i send you with e-mail or something?

Comment: Can't you filter out the unrelated `<input>` tags? Or use justpaste.it or something?

Comment: i deleted some parts and posted. Thank you for your help.